# What does the expected packet loss option in libopus (ffmpeg) actually do to the encoded file?

Tags: ffmpeg, voip

I am encoding some files into the opus format in ffmpeg using the VoIP application setting (this is for research).

One of the parameters you can set is Expected Packet Loss (%). I understand the principles behind packet loss, however, I can't work out what this setting actually does to the resulting file, as there is no transmission taking place.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more packet loss you specify, the more redunant data is encoded in the file to be able to cope with it.

http://blogs.asterisk.org/2017/04/12/asterisk-opus-packet-loss-fec/

> As mentioned FEC, is added in-band by an Opus encoder, but only after
>   being configured to do so. A previous post already discusses all the
>   available options you can set on the encoder, so be sure to check that
>   out if you haven’t already. Here though we’ll discuss some of those
>   options and how they work in combination to make it so the encoder
>   includes FEC data. As stated in the Opus FAQ several conditions must
>   be met before the encoder will add error correction to frames:
>
> - The feature must be enabled. The “fec” option must be set for a
>     defined format (note, options for codec Opus for Asterisk can be set
>     in in codecs.conf ). This option defaults to “no”, so if you don’t
>     specifically enable it Asterisk will not include FEC data when
>     encoding.
> - **The encoder must be told to expect loss. This means an
>     estimated packet loss percentage must also be specified. Setting this
>     shifts the threshold at which the encoder will start to include FEC
>     data. The higher the number the lower the threshold.**
> - The codec must be
>     operating in a mode conducive to lower bandwidths. Make sure the
>     maximum bandwidth is set to narrow or medium. This can be achieved by
>     adjusting the “max_bandwidth” option. You can do this either directly
>     by setting the option itself, or indirectly by setting the
>     “max_playback_rate” option to 16khz or less.
>
> Don’t forget to make sure
>   both sides have negotiated for FEC. If everything is properly set up,
>   but one side does not offer FEC (“useinbandfec=yes“) then it will not
>   be enabled.